# How to add data into ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models

I can't find it anywhere, so your help will be nice for me :) Here is that field:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(fragmentCategory)
```

FragmentCategory:

```
class fragmentCategory(models.Model):

        CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
                        ('val1', 'value1'),
                        ('val2', 'value2'),
                        ('val3', 'value3'),
                        )

        name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

Here is the form to send:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="val1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="val2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="val3" />
```

---

I tried something like this:

```
categories = fragmentCategory.objects.get(id=1),
```

Or:

```
categories = [1,2]
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

There's a whole page of the Django documentation [devoted to this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/), well indexed from the contents page.

As that page states, you need to do:

```
my_obj.categories.add(fragmentCategory.objects.get(id=1))
```

or

```
my_obj.categories.create(name='val1')
```

Comment: Do you then need to call `my_obj.save()` to save the update or is this done automatically?

Comment: @CpILL Seems to be done automatically. Try it out in `python manage.py shell`.

Comment: as this doc you need call .save too : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @mehdi You only need to call save the first time that you create the object with the many to many field so that it gets a primary key. After that the behavior is that you can add without saving.

Comment: Ans is right just need more clarification object of what so sir please edit the answer.

Answer (score 7):

In case someone else ends up here struggling to customize admin form Many2Many saving behaviour, you can't call `self.instance.my_m2m.add(obj)` in your `ModelForm.save` override, as `ModelForm.save` later populates your m2m from `self.cleaned_data['my_m2m']` which overwrites your changes. Instead call:

```
my_m2ms = list(self.cleaned_data['my_m2ms'])
my_m2ms.extend(my_custom_new_m2ms)
self.cleaned_data['my_m2ms'] = my_m2ms
```

(It is fine to convert the incoming QuerySet to a list - the `ManyToManyField` does that anyway.)