# Assigning a value to a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

This is my first time using a many-to-many relationship in Django. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a patient model `modelPatient` that can be assigned to multiple students (medical students) and each student `modelStudent` can have multiple patients to examine.

For this purpose, I decided to use a many-to-many relationship here:

```
class modelPatient(models.Model):
    student = models.ManyToManyField(modelStudent,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
```

and this is the student model:

```
class modelStudent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
```

Now suppose I am doing something like this:

```
patient = modelPatient.object.get(patient_name="John")
```

How can I assign this `patient` to multiple students `studentA` and `studentB`?

```
studentA = modelStudent.objects.get(first_name="john")
studentB = modelStudent.objects.get(first_name="adam")
```

What I want here is to have the `patient` instance associated with both `studentA` and `studentB`. Please let me know if this is possible or if my design decision is incorrect.

Comment: ahh so `patient.student.add(studentA)` ?

Comment: I wasnt sure if this was the right design decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

```
patient = modelPatient.object.get(patient_name="John")
studentA = modelStudent.objects.get(first_name="john")
studentB = modelStudent.objects.get(first_name="adam")
patient.student.add(studentA, studentB)
```

Also FYI about `modelPatient` - `model` here is redundant, as well as `patient` in `patient_name`. You are already doing this as part of `Patient` model namespace

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: [how to add data into ManyToManyField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182380/how-to-add-data-into-manytomanyfield)

Simply add them to your relationship with:

```
patient.student.add(studentA)
patient.student.add(studentB)
```

or you can add both of them at in one line with

```
patient.student.add(studentA, studentB)
```

For more see the docs, which give you really good examples:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Also keep in mind that you can access `patient` from `student` object.