# Django views.py: Add to favorites page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to edit an html page so a logged in user can favorite a `video.id`

Here is the **.html** file

```
<td>
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'foobar:favourite_post' video.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='video' value={{ video.id }}>
        <button type='submit'>Bookmark</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Here is the **urls.py** file

```
app_name = 'foobar'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.f_ListView.as_view(), name='overview'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.f_DetailView.as_view(), name='detailview'),
    path('<int:fav_id>/favourite_post/', views.favourite_post, name='favourite_post'),
]
```

Here is the **view.py** file

```
def favourite_post(request, fav_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=fav_id)
    if request.method == 'POST': #Then add this video to users' favourite
        video.

   return render(request, 'foobar/%s' % fav_id)
```

How to edit the **views.py** file so it is registered in the database that the user has favorited this video ?

Here is the **models.py** file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    videofile = models.FileField(upload_to="static/videos/"),
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectUser, related_name="fav_videos", blank=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, check this answer about the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182380/how-to-add-data-into-manytomany-field

Comment: Is ProjectUser the auth user model? If not how are they related?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes Daniel you are right and I updated the question to include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def favourite_post(request, fav_id):
video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=fav_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video.favourite.add(request.user)
        # Rest code
    return render(request, 'foobar/%s' % fav_id)
```

Comment: Or `request.user.fav_videos.add(video)`, which is exactly equivalent but might express the intent a bit more clearly.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with this answer. You should ask a new question showing the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be so obvious, you need to first get the current logged in user by

```
request.user
```

if your view function does not require a user to be logged in so you will need to check

```
if request.user is not None
```

then add it to the list of favorites to the video

```
video.favorite.add(request.user)
```

read more in official docs. [many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)